# Como resolver este programa con el metodo string?

Tags: string

Ingresar el nombre del archivo y su extensión mostrar en pantalla el solo la extensión.Usar el valor centinela para indicar el fin del ciclo

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado? en que lenguaje vas a trabajar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.